# Custom uitablecellview internal inconsistency exception

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I'm getting this error -

```
*** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-258.1/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1510
2014-01-13 18:58:55.829 ReviewApp[1678:3c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The error is apparent..but I'm not sure why it's happening. This is how I'm registering the nib -

```
UINib* dqNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DQCardView" bundle:nil];
UINib* simpleListNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleListCell" bundle:nil];
UINib* photoPostNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotoPostCell" bundle:nil];
[self.listView registerNib:dqNib forCellReuseIdentifier:DQCellIdentifier];
[self.listView registerNib:simpleListNib forCellReuseIdentifier:SimpleListCellIdentifier];
[self.listView registerNib: photoPostNib forCellReuseIdentifier:ListPhotoPostIdentifier];
```

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm doing this(my code is fairly long so I've summarize) -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   DQCell* dqCell;
   SimpleListCell* listCell;
   PhotoPostCell* photoCell;

   if(condition1){
        listCell = [self.listView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleListCellIdentifier];
        //do other stuff       
        return listCell;
   } else {
        dQcell = [self.listView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: DQCellIdentifier];
        //do other stuff        
        return dQcell;
   }

}
```

The listCell line gives me the exception..but the Dqcell line does not.

Further, in the listCell implementation I don't seem to be resizing the textView anywhere. 
So what's going on? What should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'", I would guess that somewhere in your code regarding a UITextView resize, you're doing something from a background thread?

Any time I'm ever doing something on a background thread, such as sending an HTTP request to a server asynchronously, and I want to display something whilst inside this background thread, such as pop up with an alertView with an error, I wrap that code in the following:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

This basically tells the OS to do whatever is in that block *on the main thread*. In the case where I pop up with an alert view while on a background thread, and when I've forgotten to do the above, the app basically locks for some period of time, seemingly broken, and randomly at a later time typically 6 or 7 seconds later, the alert pops up on screen and the app is usable again. Simple rule of thumb: ***don't do ANYTHING UI related on a background thread.***

In your case, without looking at the entire project I wouldn't know exactly what is causing the issue. Hopefully I've given you enough information to help!